# What is the maximum of the self root $f(x) = x^{1/x}$

Tags: calculus, arithmetic, exponential-function

This is a knowledge sharing question as I have answered it below. I am demonstrating how one would differentiate an expression such as $x^{1/x}$ and proving the following statement.

What is the maximum of the function: $f(x) = x^{1/x}$?

[NOTE] Proof that the found critical point is the maximum is still in progress.

Comment: I was sharing my knowledge not homework. I saw that you could answer your own questions Q&A style.

Comment: What's up with the reasoning to put on hold? Seems to be a perfectly valid question to me, at least nothing similar to "Homework question".

Comment: This site is meant as a Q&A-site for questions, with which you stuck and for which you need other peoples help. It is not meant as a site where we create a repository of problems & answers out of some books or from your own compilations. (Why not creating such a site if it does not yet exist?)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms That is not true. Answering your own question is OK, so long as you pretend you're on "Jeopardy!". See [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), or look for a certain tick-box at the bottom of the page next time you ask a question.

Comment: @user: at the moment as you begin to "pretend" something (or promote such a behave or accept it for the MSE) I've no more intention to continue any discussion and I get aware, that we users disagree about the basic intention of this site.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I am not claiming to hold an opinion about the basic intention of this site. Rather, I am pointing out an existing functionality. What I have an opinion about is that someone should not be criticised for using this functionality.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms, now, if someone gets stuck on this problem and comes to this website for a solution, it's waiting for them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**: $e^{e^{-1}}$

**Proof**:

If we take the derivative of $f(x)$ we can understand where the gradient of the line is zero. The maximum of the curve should the only place where this happens.

*Taking the derivative of $f(x)$*

$$\frac d {dx}(x^{1/x})$$
Rearrange $x^{1/x}$ as an exponent of $e$
$$\frac d {dx}\left(\exp\left[\frac{\ln x}x\right]\right)$$
Using the chain rule:
$$\frac d {dx}f\circ g = \frac {df}{dg} \frac{dg}{dx}$$
We can rearrange our expression letting $u =\frac {\ln x}x$
$$\frac {d\space\exp(u)}{du} \frac{du}{dx}$$
We can simplify because we are differentiating $e$
$$\exp(u)\frac {du}{dx}$$
Remember $\exp(u) = x^{1/x}$ so now we can write the expression as:
$$x^{1/x}\left( \frac d {dx}\left(\frac {\ln x} x\right) \right)$$
We can now work out the derivative in our expression using the quotient rule:
$$\frac d {dx}\left(\frac uv\right) = \frac {v\frac {du} {dx} - u \frac{dv}{dx}}{x^2}$$
$$\frac d {dx}\left(\frac {\ln x}{x}\right) = \frac {x\frac {d\ln x} {dx} - \ln x\frac{dx}{dx}}{x^2}$$
$$ = \frac {x\frac 1x - \ln x}{x^2} = \frac {1 - \ln x}{x^2} $$
Finally we can now say that
$$\frac d {dx}(x^{1/x}) = x^{1/x}\frac {1 - \ln x}{x^2} $$

**Proving that $f(e)$ is the only critical point**

There exists a critical point at point $p$ such that $f'(p) = 0$. This implies that there has to be a factor of $0$ in $f'(p)$. As there are only two factors, $\frac {1-\ln x}{x^2}$ has to be the zeroing factor as $x^{1/x} ≠ 0$ this is because no real number $x$ can satisfy $0^x=x$ as $0^n=0$.

For $\frac {1-\ln x}{x^2}$ to equal $0$. The numerator has to be $0$. For $1-\ln x$ to be equal to $0$, $\ln x$ has to be $$\ln x = 1$$ raising both sides as a power of $e$ $$x=e$$
This shows that the only real solution to $f'(p) = 0$ is $e$. This is the only critical point.

**Proving that the only critical point is the maximum of $f(x)$**

Take a second derivative $f(x) \implies f''(x)$. We can tell if the critical point, which we have identified at $f(e)$ is the maximum or minimum. The concept works as such. Let $k$ be some number such that $g(k)$ is a critical point and $g(x)$ is some function. The following outcomes conclude whether or not our critical is maximum or minimum.
$$g''(k) <0$$Then $g(k)$ is maximum.
$$g''(k) >0$$Then $g(k)$ is minimum.
$$g''(k) = 0$$ Then the test is inconclusive.

$f''(e) < 0 \implies f(e) = \max.$

Comment: Just as something to note: It's always good to check what happens at critical points as well, in this case $x = 0$ however in this case, the derivative at $0$ is $0$ (via a limiting argument).

Comment: Formally the function is defined *only* for $\,x>0\,$ ...

Comment: @CameronWilliams $0^{1/0}$ is not a number.

Comment: $f(x)\xrightarrow[x\to 0^+]{} 0$, so one can extend it by continuity with $f(0)=0$. But in your derivation, **(a)** it is now enough to have $f'(e)=0$ to conclude $f$ is maximum at $x=e$;  you should also state that $f'(x) > 0$ (resp. ($f'(x) < 0$) for $x < e$ (resp. $x > e$).  **(b)** Additionally, the maximum is $f(e)=e^{1/e}$, not $e$.

Comment: You should correct also the introducing remark, for instance "Answer: the maximum is at x=e and its value is f(x)=exp(exp(-1))~ 1.444... "

Comment: I don't see where you demonstrated that $x=e$ gives a maximum as opposed to a minimum or a saddle-point.